# React Native - launchPackager.command cant be opened

Tags: ios, react-native

I am having trouble building react native ios project.

Error message:

```
"launchPackage command" can't be opened because it is from an unidentified developer.
```

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 25):

Although [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47161182) answer will most likely work, you would also allow all future apps from unidentified developers to be installed without being prompted.

To allow executing only the command in question (`launchPackager.command`), go to your react-native installation folder (most likely `node_modules/react-native/scripts`) in Finder and right-click `launchPackager.command`, choose `Open` and confirm by clicking `Open` again.

You will not be prompted again for this command as you have allowed execution specifically.

Answer (score 16):

Another simple way is to delete node_modules folder from project directory and do npm install.
This happened because project was copied from old mac which had node_modules folder created by that old mac user, hence some problem occurs for project transferred to new mac.

Comment: This was exactly my problem and seems like the most secure solution.

Comment: The best solution, it works like a magic.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Note that if you're using pnpm, deleting `node_modules` is not sufficient because they're hard-linked from pnpm's content-addressable store. You need to delete them from that location as well before reinstalling.

Answer (score 12):

on MacOS Catalina and above
Go to

- System Preferences
- Security & Privacy
- Choose tab "Privacy"
- Select "Developer Tools" on left pane
- Check "Terminal" to allow terminal to run software locally which does not meet system's  security policy . (please be aware of potential implications of this action and make sure that you know what you are doing )

Answer (score 11):

Had the same problem on macOS Mojave.
This helped:

```
chmod 777 node_modules/react-native/scripts/launchPackager.command
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, after trying all the others above. The launchPackager.command file was missing +x permission at fs level.

Answer (score 6):

Go to

1. System Preferences
2. Security & Privacy
3. Choose tab `General`
4. Choose `Allow apps downloaded from anywhere` or `Allow apps downloaded from App Store and identified developers`

I had the same error with you and this method worked for me.

Comment: Do not do this! This disables a critical security feature on your mac! See the response from @malte

Answer (score 5):

Check this answer if you are using [`oh-my-zsh terminal`](https://ohmyz.sh/)

I was getting this error on `zsh terminal` because there was an update. Whenever terminal opened it was saying me to press `Y` to update and whenever I run the `npx react-native run-android` `zsh terminal` was giving this update causing failed to launch metro server.

To fix this error simply open your `zsh terminal`, press `Y` to update and after this run your `react-native` app using `npx react-native run-android`/

Answer (score 1):

```
chmod 777 node_modules/react-native/scripts/launchPackager.command
```

- open terminal and Run the above command
- after that Run the `react-native run-android`
- Works for Me, It will Run :)

Answer (score 1):

**Check zsh's update request**

In my case: zsh asks if you want to update and need to answer

```
[oh-my-zsh] Would you like to update? [Y/n] 
[oh-my-zsh] You can update manually by running `omz update`
```

It breaks the bundle's boot process

**Solution: open new terminal tab and answer the update request then run again**

Comment: that was exactly the issue in my case 

Answer (score -2):

The reason is because you downloaded source code using virtual machine.

**Solution:**

Please download source code at your real machine.

And then copy it at VM, and build this project.