# How I make sure react-native is signed?

Tags: xcode, macos, react-native, node-modules

I was having an issue with react-native not working because it is not signed. There is a [question about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219152/react-native-launchpackager-command-cant-be-opened/47161182) on SO already. The problem is  I can't use that solution, I am trying to distribute a .zip file with react-native already  inside the "node_modules" folder, so people can build it easily, so I need to get it signed instead, I can't go around telling people downloading my file to just disable their MacOS security...

Answer (score 1):

Create an Apple development account by using your email and add it in your Xcode, `Project Navigator > Signing & Capabilities > Signing (Debug)`, mark the `Automatically manage signing`:

[image: automatic signing]

Add the bundle identifier name as this patter:

```
com.[developer account name].[project name]
```

Then you will be able to build your application on your physical device.