# “launchPackager.command” can’t be opened

Tags: react-native, macos, metro-bundler, macos-ventura

Just updated my Mac to the official release of Ventura, and I cannot launch my application via `react-native run-ios`.

**Expected behavior:**

running `react-native run-ios` will launch an Xcode simulator and a terminal window with Metro running.

**Current behavior:**

Xcode simulator opens, main terminal says app was built successfully, but an error is thrown instead of the metro terminal opening:

> “launchPackager.command” can’t be opened because (null) is not allowed to open documents in Terminal.

The simulator just shows a white screen and can't be interacted with.

**What I've tried:**

- manually opening `node_modules/react-native/scripts/launchPackager.command`

  - opens Metro terminal but is not connected to the app

> warn No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.
> info Reloading app...

- giving Terminal full disk access (no change)

Comment: [@author](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74187734/16104229) were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: @KartikBhalla the solution below by gpmcadam worked for me.  I was using the warp terminal at the time, but have switched back to iTerm and it works for that as well.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This happened to me after upgrading to macOS Ventura. I happen to use iTerm as my main terminal, **not** the built-in Terminal.app so the following fix *only applies to that scenario*:

#### Set iTerm as the Default Handler for *.command Files

1. Open **node_modules/react-native/scripts/** in Finder (`open node_modules/react-native/scripts/`)
2. Right-Click on **launchPackager.command** and click **Open With** then choose **Other...**
3. In your Applications directory, select **iTerm** and click **Always Open With**

After this, you might need to run `npm run ios` again from this terminal window. However, from now on, Metro will open in a new iTerm tab instead of trying to open the command in a new Terminal window.

For me, this was the desired behaviour and it removed this warning.

**Note** In future, any `*.command` files will now open with iTerm instead of Terminal.

Comment: This sorta works for me, and I had essentially found the same workaround but using the Warp terminal.  It's just a little frustrating that the command doesn't run automatically.  I still have to close the app in simulator, reopen, and reload metro to get it to bundle

Comment: What about android ? I run the command ```react-native run-android``` and I get the error only in the visual studio code own terminal and not with the Terminal app itself .

Comment: Actually I don't see iTerm in my Applications folder

Comment: If not finding it in Applications, look in Utilities folder, then should see Terminal

Answer (score 11):

In project.pbxproj file
Change ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING = **YES**; to ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING = **NO**;

And run the simulator with usual command

- For IOS - npx react-native run-ios

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same problem as you, I installed another terminal (iTerm2), then randomly found a .command file, and in the display introduction, changed the default opening method to iTerm2[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbvCU.png)

Answer (score 3):

I'm having this issue after upgrading my MacOS to Ventura 13.1.

If you don't want to use iTerm as the accepted answer suggest, the workaround I found was to look for the `launchPackager.command` file inside `node-modules/react-native/scripts/` and open this file manually every time you run your app for the first time (specifically when the error pop-up appears). This will open the terminal with metro running already.

I know that manually processes are not the best, but I don't want to use iTerm :)

Answer (score 2):

**For Most of the case you just have to delete node_modules and install modules again (npm i)**. This happens when project was copied from old mac which had node_modules folder created by the old user, or if the system thinks so

This happened to me after i configured my terminal for the look and feel - but with iterm2, oh my zsh, and powerlevel10k

Answer (score 1):

Using **Intel version** of apps (Webstorm, Android Studio, other IDE etc...) fixed my problems. I encountered the same issue and thanks to Intel version of Webstorm and Xcode on Rosetta I can able to pod install and other operations.

Note: I'm using Intel version of Android Studio, WebStorm. Also Xcode uses Rosetta 2. No problem detected and everything works perfect. I can able to develop React-Native & Native Android & iOS and Flutter apps without problem. Before that I was using Silicon version of WebStorm and almost no function worked.

Config: MacBook Air, macOS Ventura 13.2 on Apple M1 processor.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you using VSCode terminal to run the command? If so, try running the command on the Mac default terminal instead.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem as you, I found a workaround for that, just run this command in the VSCode terminal

```
npm run start
```

in another tab run this:

```
npx react-native run-ios
```

or

```
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 14"
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, It happened, cause zsh update alert was opened at the same time.
May be, You also could see this alert,
"do you want to update zsh or no"
so I guess this alert disturbs automatically running metro server on Iterm or Iterm2 terminal.
so, I just updated followed by this alert, and then, It work well.

I referenced this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76265442/12959959