# LaunchPackager.command” can’t be opened because (null) is not allowed to open documents in Terminal : React Native Mac OS

Tags: android, react-native, macos, terminal

I tried to build my react-native application using `npx react-native run-android` command. App builds successfully but metro blunder not opening and return following error message.

```
launchPackager.command” can’t be opened because (null) is not allowed to open documents in Terminal.
```

Anyone has an idea to fix this issue ?

My machine specifications : MacBook Pro M1, macOS Ventura 13

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: @Bharath not yet, But It's happening because of the macOs Ventura

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a one solution but need to do it manually.

Go to your project folder -> node modules -> react native -> scripts -> open "launchPackager.command"

you all good now

Comment: Check my answer for permanent solution

Answer (score 0):

i found solution to this in other thread....

[“launchPackager.command” can’t be opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74187734/launchpackager-command-can-t-be-opened)

but i wanted to fix the issue and keep using default terminal instead of using different terminal options....if anyone gets a solution for it plz do reply.

same os version - ventura.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that this script couldn't find the application to run this command.

Permanent solution:
Set iTerm as the Default Handler for *.command Files

- Open node_modules/react-native/scripts/ in Finder (open node_modules/react-native/scripts/)
- Right-click on launchPackager.command and click Open With then choose Other...
- In your Applications directory, select iTerm and click Always Open With