# '1' cannot be opened because '(null)' is not allowed to open documents in Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

`1` is a file, which is compiled by g++. When I execute the following command in iterm2

```bash
bash -c "open -a Terminal.app 1"
```

an error pops up

[image]

Translate the Chinese in the picture into English:

**'1' cannot be opened because '(null)' is not allowed to open documents in Terminal.**

Why does this error occur? How to solve it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this post answer your question? (not quite a duplicate, but similar) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74187734/launchpackager-command-can-t-be-opened

Comment: @JustinHendrickson Thank you, I've seen that post before, but it didn't solve my problem. Also, I don't want to use iterm as a terminal, I want to use what comes with mac.

Answer (score 0):

it is an underlying bug in macOS Ventura with Terminal.
the solution is to wait for Apple to update the version, or use the previous system version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).